# Confused jQuery .prev()

Tags: jquery

I successfully change the button value when I click the button with using $('#btn').prev().text('new string'); but I don't know why .prev() should be used

According to http://api.jquery.com/prev/ , .prev() is  searching for the predecessor of each of these elements in the DOM but not existing element.

When click any button, should the button 1 be changed instead of button 2?

HTML

```
<button value="Button 1" id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<button value="Button 2" id="btn2">Button 2</button>
<button value="Button 3" id="btn3">Button 3</button>
```

Javascript

```
$(function (e) {

    $(':button').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#btn2').prev().text('Click');
    });
})
```

Comment: don't just post the jsfiddle link... post the code also

Comment: ..Which you get told to do when writing the question.

Comment: You are using jquery mobile and it changes the markup structure of the buttons. Inspect the element to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are using jQuery mobile which changes the structure of the elements:

```
<div class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" data-disabled="false" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner">Button 2</span>
    <button id="btn2" class="ui-btn-hidden" value="Button 2" data-disabled="false">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

As you can see the previous element here is a `span` element. The following snippet changes the previous `.ui.btn`'s *visible* textContent by updating the `span`'s textContent:

```
$('#btn2').closest('.ui-btn') // get the closest `.ui-btn` parent 
          .prev()  // get the previous element
          .find('span.ui-btn-inner') // find the span
          .text('Click');
```

Comment: Thanks BlackSheep, it is a good practice to change the button text if using jQuery mobile?

Comment: @user3059850 You are welcome, well, there is nothing wrong with changing textContent of an element.